# Visual Studio Xamarin.iOS Xcode Objective-C - WKWebView implementation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I am currently trying to display a simple HTML-page within my iOS app used to control my smart mirror, which is supposed to display the current content displayed by the mirror. Unfortunately, I can't find any helpful tutorials online (only for the programming language Swift, which I am not allowed to use) and can't figure out how to properly implement WKWebView. If anyone could provide me with a useful tutorial or maybe even guide me through the steps, I would be very thankful!

EDIT: I've made some progress, however, the page won't load and will only display a white screen.

It is supposed to display a loading indicator (until the page is loaded), which is displayed for a fraction of a second before the screen turns white.

Here's my code:

"ThirdViewController.h":

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>


@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController <WKNavigationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

@end
```

"ThirdViewController.m":

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@implementation ThirdViewController
@synthesize webView;
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.178.34:8080/"];
                  NSURLRequest *urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    
    [webView loadRequest:urlReq];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}

- (void) webViewdidCommitNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
- (void) webViewdidFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
}

@end
```

I have also added the following to Info.plist to allow for the use of non-https URLs:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Sincerely,
Lukas

Comment: have you read the docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/webview

Comment: Yes, unfortunately without success.

Comment: why do you have this tagged Xamarin?

Comment: Because I'm using Xamarin.iOS in conjunction with Xcode on my Mac.

Comment: none of the code you posted is C#

Comment: I know, it's objective-c, which I'm not very familiar with. Visual Studio automatically synchronizes the code back to C#.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same effect with the Objecive-C, you could have a try with following C# code:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    private readonly NSUrl url = new NSUrl("https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/");

    public UIActivityIndicatorView indicatorView;
    protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }

    partial void OpenWebView(UIButton sender)
    {
        indicatorView = new UIActivityIndicatorView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width/2 - 25, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height/2 - 25, 25 ,25));
        indicatorView.Hidden = true;
        var webView = new WKWebView(View.Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration());
        View.AddSubview(webView);
        View.AddSubview(indicatorView);
        webView.NavigationDelegate = new CustomNavigationDelegate(this);
        webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(url));
    }

    partial void OpenSafari(UIButton sender)
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
    }

    partial void OpenSafariViewController(UIButton sender)
    {
        var viewController = new SFSafariViewController(url);
        PresentViewController(viewController, true, null);
    }
}

internal class CustomNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    private ViewController viewController;

    public CustomNavigationDelegate(ViewController viewController)
    {
        this.viewController = viewController;
    }

    public override void DidCommitNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {
        viewController.indicatorView.Hidden = true;
        viewController.indicatorView.StartAnimating();
    }

    public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {
        viewController.indicatorView.StopAnimating();
        viewController.indicatorView.HidesWhenStopped = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

I have given up on the Visual Studio Xamarin.iOS Xcode combo after my code in Xcode has been deleted several times while building the application in Visual Studio. I am now using Xcode and Swift instead.

Comment: @LukasGrabowski Okey, that's great you have solved that. You could update your answer when you have time. And if my reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.